# Usually by algorithm's, but not in this case

Tags: knowledge, cipher, visual

The task is to decipher the picture below and then replace the question marks!

[image]

Comment: Why are there different question marks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The picture depicts:

> Hungarian flag and a cube

These resemble a famous:

> Cube from Hungary: Rubik's Cube!

Translating it:

> 18 21 2 9 11 19 3 21 2 5 -- with A1Z26 translation.

Comment: Yes, correct! :)

Comment: It's not a cube; the b ack is wider than the front. :)

Comment: Hehe, it's a special one then :)